# C#: path format such as \\.\c:\ or \\DOMAIN\c:\ not supported

Tags: c#, windows, file

I'm tring to delete a folder for which one of its subfolders has the name "con", which is a reserved device name, so C# throws an exception.

In CMD, I can delete such a folder with `rmdir \\.\c:\con`, but in C# I've tried lots of variations on this and always get that the path format is unsupported. For example, the following does not work: `Directory.Delete("\\\\" + Environment.UserDomainName + "\\c:\\test")`.

Please note that I do not want to depend on external commands such as CMD's `del` command, etc.

Comment: use Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer) + @"c:\test"

Comment: @Polly it works for normal folder name like "test"
but i'm trying remove a folder with names such "con , com4 "and et. witch are blocked in windows ,  using your code throw an exception to for removing c:\con <br> please run {mkdir \\.\c:\con  } in cmd and try removing it by c#

Comment: okey, you can call hided terminal window and use "rmdir \\.\c:con" from there as a variant

Comment: as i said i don't want to depend on emdir.exe or et. thanks for helping

Comment: FYI, "\\Domain\c:\test" is invalid. When using the redirector, the hidden drive share is "C$", e.g.  "\\Domain\C$\test". A path such as "\\?\C:\test" or "\\.\C:\test" is a local device path, not a UNC network share. The underlying implementations are completely different. A UNC path actually ends up translated to "\\?\UNC\server\share\..." using the UNC device, which is a link to the MUP device nowadays.

Comment: @eryksun 
thanks for correction , Directory.Delete(@"\\"+Environment.UserDomainName+@"\C$\test"); didin't work too

Comment: I was just correcting the syntax for a UNC path with a drive-letter share such as "C$". Only a locale-device path can bypass the runtime library's handling of implicit DOS devices in directories. In this case, sometimes both "\\?\" and "\\.\" paths work equivalently, but not always, and of the two only "\\?\" supports long paths that exceed `MAX_PATH` (Windows 10 long paths notwithstanding). Stick with "\\?\" for filesystem paths such as "\\?\C:\test" and "\\.\" for device paths such as "\\.\nul".

Comment: You might be able to do this with AlphaFS though I admit that I haven't checked. However I've had great success using that library for other things (like long file paths and other file/device related items not supported/available in the framework classes) http://alphafs.alphaleonis.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must bypass the .net framework and delete the file using the `\\?\c:\con` notation with a p/invoke to a `RemoveDirectory` call

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError=true)]
static extern bool RemoveDirectory(string lpPathName);

public static DeleteBadDir()
{
     RemoveDirectory(@"\\?\c:\con");
}
```

Comment: i thought about this but this shouldn't work when the folder is not empty 
in msdn for this function the directory must be empty

Comment: There is a recursive example on [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/RemoveDirectory.html) that deletes the folder's content too.